# why I'm getting a "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a class that gets the source code from a URL. I dont understand why I get a "cannot find symbol error" on this line:

`catch (MalformaedURLException e)`

If someone could explain whats wrong that would be wonderful...Thanks

Here is my whole code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class SourceCode
{
private String source;
public SourceCode(String url)
{
    try
    {
        URL page = new URL(url);
        this.source = getSource(page);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getSource(URL url) throws Exception
{

        URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));
        String strLine = "";

        spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );


        while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            strLine = strLine + "\n";
        }
        return strLine;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to import `java.net.MalformedURLException`

Comment: Spelling for MalformedURLException is wrong....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this code.

1. You are missing the import for `java.net.MalformedURLException`
2. `getSource()` is not returning anything, you need to return a string from the method.
3. You are setting `spoof.setRequestProperty` after starting to read from the source
4. Your constructor is ignoring the exception instead of throwing it out
5. There is no getter for source

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class SourceCode {
    private String source;

    public SourceCode(URL pageURL) throws IOException {
        this.source = getSource(pageURL);
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    private String getSource(URL url) throws IOException {
        URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        spoof.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));

        String strLine = "";
        while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(strLine);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SourceCode s = new SourceCode(new URL("https://www.google.co.in/"));
        System.out.println(s.getSource());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot!